# Using TOP (1) in SQL Server for getting the most number of occurrences of a string in a column

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have two columns:

```
INDEX     NAME
 125      john
 125      dave
 125      dave
 130      john
 131      dave
```

I want to return only the name with the most number of occurrences. Then I want to put the string into a variable. What's a query that I can use to achieve this?

This is with SQL Server 2008 and C#

Comment: I have a table that I'm filling with names. Don't mind the index. I want to make a query to the database that will return the name that appears the most.

I've been using `SELECT TOP (1) name, COUNT(*) FROM names_table GROUP BY name`
But it isn't quite working out. As I've tried the query in MS-SQL Management Studio and it doesn't return the right value, just seems as though it returns them (if i write 10 instead of 1) in ascending order by letter. So the top occurent value that I should be getting isn't actually top occurent, just top in letter ascending order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it may give you what you are looking for.

```
SELECT TOP 1 name 
  FROM names_table 
 GROUP BY name
 ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC;
```

This is similar to what you tried originally.  Just move the count() to the order by, rather than the select list.

Comment: Why the derived table? Just do it in one. `SELECT TOP 1 name FROM table GROUP BY name ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC`.

Comment: good point. SELECT TOP 1 name 
FROM @tbl 
GROUP BY name 
ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC;
 works just fine too, and is much cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

LinqToSql:

```
string mostFrequentName = myDataContext.Records
  .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
  .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
  //.ThenBy(g => g.Key)  in case of ties, use this for consistent results
  .Select(g => g.Key)
  .FirstOrDefault();
```

---

Sql:

```
SELECT top 1 Name
FROM Records
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Count(*) desc --, Name   --in case of ties
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using LINQ, you can do it as follows:

```
var topName = MyDataContext.MyTable
  .OrderByDescending( x => x.Index )
  .Take( 1 )
  .Select( x => x.Name );
```